# PHP 7.1.9 portable webserver issues

Tags: php, webserver, portability

So I have a Portable Webserver program called USBWebserver,
because the original program still uses php 5.3 (I believe) I went on an adventure to upgrade it so that not only me but the rest of my class can use it.

- I upgraded the Apache server build to 2.4.27
- I upgraded the PHP binary to 7.1.9

The thing is... Everything functions but one thing:
For some reason MBString (Yes, just MBString) will not start up with a variable path anymore. If I set a manual path it functions it just no longer does this with a variable one.

Before people say:"Then why don't you just make it a manual path and be done with it." because it needs to stay portable and usable "out of the box" so to say.

I am quite stuck on how to fix this issue. If any info is needed, please ask and I will edit this post with the info. (Like if you need php.ini)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more messing about with it I finally found out what fixed this issue. I'll post it here so that others who might try to do this won't have this hurdle to combat.

extension_dir's path at first was "php\ext" as php.exe wasn't liking that I changed it to ext, which php.exe liked but apache...not so much.

After a long while I changed the path to extension_dir = ".\php\ext" and as if the gate of heaven opened... it functioned. Fully and completely without even one error.

So now I have a modified USBWebserver running:

- PHP 7.1.9
- Apache 2.4.27
- PHPMyAdmin 4.0.4.2
- MySQL 5.6.13

Fully portable, fully fuctional. I hope this little tid bit of info helps someone else some day and if some people want the program, ask and I will make a download link and edit it into my original post any this answer.

Comment: where you change extension_dir = ".\php\ext"

Answer (score 0):

Have you been updating usbwebserver to newer version?
It seems that the officiel development has stopped.

I have tried to update php to version 8, but then the apache server won't start, and there is noting in the log file - its just empty.

Thanks
Jorgensen

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32245207)